# how to remove AM and PM from OwlDateTime in angular (cause its already in 24 hours format)

Tags: angular, typescript

OwlDateTime with 24 hours format:

```html
<div *ngIf="isSchedule"  class="form-inline">
 <label style='margin-right:5px ;margin-left:210px'>
  Date Time:
  <input [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt" [owlDateTime]="dt"  class="form-control" placeholder="Date time Picker" (change)="getScheduledTime($event)">
  <owl-date-time #dt></owl-date-time>
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: when it is in 24 hours format it doesn't show AM PM. so what do you want?

Comment: its showing AM and PM

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/github/DanielYKPan/owl-examples/tree/date-time-picker

Comment: In Basic mode only the clock is shown no AM PM?

Comment: yes but once you will select both date and time it will append AM/PM

Comment: Ah ok i'll check that

Comment: when i am selecting time its showing in 24 hr but actually its getting update in test box in 12 hr format

Comment: i want time in 24 hr format

Comment: I think you have to as @danday74

Comment: Anybody got solutions of this?Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Docs:

https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/#locale-formats

There are various approaches available but I would suggest the `moment.js` format which is most flexible.  You need to use this:

```
npm install ng-pick-datetime-moment moment --save
```

Then use the approach below, making changes to the properties flagged with CHANGE THIS to a more suitable `moment.js` format:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS} from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { OwlMomentDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime-moment';

// See the Moment.js docs for the meaning of these formats:
// https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
export const MY_MOMENT_FORMATS = {
    parseInput: 'l LT',
    fullPickerInput: 'l LT', // CHANGE THIS TO A MOMENT.JS FORMAT
    datePickerInput: 'l', // CHANGE THIS TO A MOMENT.JS FORMAT
    timePickerInput: 'LT', // CHANGE THIS TO A MOMENT.JS FORMAT
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [OwlDateTimeModule, OwlMomentDateTimeModule],
    providers: [
        {provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS, useValue: MY_MOMENT_FORMATS},
    ],
})
export class AppExampleModule {
}
```

Here's a `moment.js` formatting cheatsheet:

https://devhints.io/moment